# Unexpected Error : `<<' unmatched. Could not locate the mistake

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script to fix missing 'F' issue. I am inserting a missing 'F' on the first line in a file. That file is log file and continuously updates with new log. However, when I am executing the script, I am getting the error as- 
./s[37]: syntax error at line 39 : `<<' unmatched. Can anyone please help me to get rid of this issue? In my another scripts I am facing same issue. I tried much but could not find what's wrong I have done. I am providing a code sample.

```
#Script to solve F issue
#----------------------------------------
#By Kapil Shirsath
#----------------------------------------

cd /var/spool/mail        #mail files reside in mail folder

filename=`ls -l | grep '^-' | sort -k 5 -rn | head -1 | tr -s " " "," | cut -d "," -f "9"`    # this will list the file with maximum size`

echo "File with maximum size is  $filename"
echo "----------------------------------------------------"
echo "Is it the file expected?(y/n)"
read choice
if test $choice == "n"
then
    echo "Exiting...."
    exit;
fi;

c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    ls -l $filename
    echo $filename
    sleep 2
    c=`expr $c + 1`
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------"

#`sudo su`   #this will give you super user permissions
echo "First line of the file is as below :"
head -1 $filename
echo "---------------------------------------"
firstline=`head -1 $filename`;
echo "Repeat : $firstline"
echo $firstline | grep ^"rom" >/dev/null
if test $? -eq 0
then
    ex -s $filename <<'EOF'
    1s/^/F/
    :wq
    EOF
    echo "F issue fixed!"
    c=1
    while [ $c -le 5 ]
    do
        ls -l $filename
        sleep 2
        c=`expr $c + 1`
    done
    echo "---------------------------------------------------"  
else
    echo "Not finding the missing 'F' ! !! Kindly check with your system "
    exit;
fi;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use spaces for indentation inside here-doc and closing `EOF`.

Keep it like this:

```
if test $? -eq 0; then
ex -s $filename <<'EOF'
1s/^/F/
:wq
EOF
echo "F issue fixed!"
c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    ls -l $filename
    sleep 2
    c=`expr $c + 1`
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------"  
else
    echo "Not finding the missing 'F' ! !! Kindly check with your system "
    exit;
fi;
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava.I will try it in a minute. And let you informed. :)

Comment: @ anubhava. I tried your suggestion and the code is working fine. Will you please tell me why not to put blank spaces inside here doc? Does shell interprets it differently?

Comment: Yes by specs leading spaces are not allowed. If you use `ex -s $filename <<-'EOF'` you can use **leading tabs** for indentation. Check `man bash` for more details.

Comment: thanks for your help. If you dont mind, please rank my question.

Comment: Yes indeed, question upvoted for including full script and all details.

Comment: .I am needing your assistance. I posted one question titled 'Accessing shell variables inside 'sudo' block : export doesn't work' on superuser. Can you please answer that?

Comment: Here is it Anubhava : http://superuser.com/questions/934864/accessing-shell-variables-inside-sudo-block-export-doesnt-work